# Using constexpr if instead of macros when writing platform dependent code?

Tags: c++, c++17

Now that `if constexpr` is part of C++17, is it a good replacement for macros when writing platform dependent code and similar?

I'm wondering, because I really do not like macros, and would like to use them only for include guards and includes.

```
// those variables should be given by the compiler
constexpr unsigned int __os = 0x1; // current os
constexpr unsigned int __os_win = 0x1; // Windows
constexpr unsigned int __os_linux = 0x2; // Linux-flavors
constexpr unsigned int __os_apple = 0x4; // Mac os

void print_os() {
    if constexpr (__os == __os_win)
        std::cout << "You're on Windows!\n";
    else if constexpr (__os == __os_linux)
        std::cout << "You're on a Linux OS!\n";
    else if constexpr (__os == __os_apple)
        std::cout << "You're on Mac OS!\n";
}
```

instead of the current solution:

```
void print_os() {
#ifdef _WIN32
    std::cout << "You're on Windows!\n";
#elif __linux__
    std::cout << "You're on a Linux OS!\n";
#elif __APPLE__
    std::cout << "You're on Mac OS!\n";
}
```

Both ways do not generate code for the other platforms when compiled, so they are technically the same, and as such, I would prefer the `constexpr` way (if it were possible).

Would this be a feasible request for compilers to implement the `constexpr` variables from above? I couldn't find any feature request and implementation for both gcc and clang, so there must be a reason why they don't want to implement the first way. Why is that so?

Comment: At first glance, it sounds like you have it backwards. This would work for include guards, but can you define them on the command line (in the make file)? I guess you can have separate folders for the command line to select: windows/config.h, apple/config.h (and e.g. -I windows) but that seems much less versatile than command line #defines. Maybe compile time eval of shell variables in the code? Is that portable?

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is backward compatibility...

Comment: @W.F. Why? I'm not suggesting to replace the macro way, just as another way.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Ohh, right... So you would like to have both defines and constexpr variables? But still you can use defined constants in `if constexpr`, can't you?...

Comment: @Rakete1111 How you're planning to inject `__os ` in your compilation process?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Good point, I don't know. Maybe some other macros that change `__os`, with the default being the current os :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A year after posting this question I now know why this is not a good idea. It's because the two are not actually equivalent.

`if constexpr` is just a facility that doesn't instantiate the discarded branch. That's it. This means that code like:

```
void draw() {
#if LINUX
    ncursesDrawWhatever();
#elif WINDOWS
    Win32Draw();
#endif
}
```

(which is perfectly fine right now) is not equivalent to:

```
void draw() {
    if constexpr (__linux)
        ncursesDrawWhatever();
    else if constexpr (__win)
        Win32Draw();
}
```

because on both platforms the two functions need to be available (and on the preprocessor version they do not). In this case the `constexpr` is completely redundant because it does nothing. Having to define both functions on both platforms just for one not being used is a bit of a pain, which is why the preprocessor was used in this way in the first place!

Comment: This is my preprocessor. There are many like it, but this one is mine. My preprocessor is my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you haven't written one. These are fairly new things in the language. It takes time for an idea like that to filter down to actual code that's implemented and changes in how things are done.

As an example, I went through the Python `asyncio` package, and despite the creation of `async` and `await` keywords in the language specifically to support the use-cases of this package, it uses them in very few places and uses the `@coroutine` decorator most places still. This wasn't really too surprising.

So, post the feature request. Ask for some nice os testing constants that can be used with `constexpr` conditionals. Or maybe even commit to digging into the library to implement them yourself. The feature is less than 2 years old. So it shouldn't be a surprise this hasn't been done yet.

Answer (score -2):

I agree, using C syntax instead of ifdefs is more readable. For backward compatibility you can suppress warnings for const conditionals, either with a compile flag or pragma.  Constexpr as a keyword is arguably no more useful than a comment to the same effect.

Comment: The question is *why are there no feature requests*?

Comment: If there is no need for a feature --- the compiler does the same without it --- then that's an obvious reason why there would be no requests for it. That doesn't require a poll of people who've made no such request, to answer the poster's question.